# Error inserting text (string) into elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

When I execute my python code I get the following error:

**RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'failed to parse')**

How can I solve this?

```
text = open('very_Important.txt', 'r').read()

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch 
es=Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost','port':9200}])

res = es.index(index='jen',doc_type='txtfile',id=1,body=text)
```

Comment: Can you show the content of `very_Important.txt`? It seems to not contain valid JSON data.

Comment: @Val indeed the content is not Json file but a String, should the body (body=text) be an Json instead of a String?

Comment: Because How would I entered I large string of text in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change your call to this:

```
res = es.index(index='jen',doc_type='txtfile',id=1,body={'text': text})
```